# openssl s_client -connect ldaphost:636, returns error message: write:errno=104

Tags: linux, active-directory, openssl

I am trying to retrieve the SSL Certificate from LDAP(Active Directory) Server.

When i try the following command(on a linux box):

```
$ openssl s_client -connect ldaphost:636
```

I get the error message:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
```

I have also tried:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect ldaphost:636 -ssl2
$ openssl s_client -connect ldaphost:636 -ssl3
$ openssl s_client -connect ldaphost:636 -stls1
```

All of them give the same error.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you try the `-no_tls1_2` option?

Comment: i tried: -no_tls1 , -no_ssl3, -no_ssl2 (same error in all cases) , cannot find any valid option called: -no_tls1_2

Comment: Are you sure that SSL is correctly set up on the Active Directory server ? 104 means the server sent a RST, which may be the behavior of Active Directory without a correct certificate, I guess. Could you look at what really happens at the network layer, using Wireshark for example ?

Comment: Remi> Yes it is possible that SSL is not correctly setup in Active Directory. But Active Directory is listening on port 636 (ssl port). I am using a Linux Box to run openssl command. Not sure how wireshark works on that.